# Running multiple macros to create separate workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro written to take selected sheets from one workbook, and copy those to another workbook, saving it under a new name.  I need to run this same query repeatedly until I create about 6 separate files.  Each individual macro works, and I can call them each up one at a time, but they will not run sequentially.  I believe I know that the problem lies in the fact that the code I have written will not reference back to the source workbook, and I don’t know how to write code to do it.

The attached code is what I am using, and it may seem a bit sloppy – I put together pieces from several different macros to get this to work.  Gqp Master is the name of the master workbook that all the other workbooks are being created from.

```
    Sub Snuth()
'This will prevent the alet from popping up when overwriting graphs, etc
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim NewBook         As Workbook
Dim strFileName     As String
Dim WS              As Worksheet
Dim WBk             As Workbook

Set WBk = ("Gap Master")

For Each WS In Worksheets
    WS.Visible = True
Next

For Each WS In Worksheets
If WS.Range("C4") <> "Snuth, John" Then
WS.Visible = False
End If

If WS.Range("C4") = "Snuth, John" Then
WS.Visible = True
End If
Next WS


FPath = "C:\Users\mmarshall\Documents\GAP\GAP Development"
FName = "Snuth GAP " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
Else
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
End If

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: So you have sevearl other macros that are similar to this, which need to be called sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have several other macros that do, more or less, the exact same thing, just for different manager names.

You can create a master subroutine that will invoke other subs/functions.  What this does is send some arguments/parameters to a subroutine, these are

- `WBk`: the workbook you're copying *from*
- `lastName`: the manager's last name
- `firstName`: the manager's first name

Here is the code:

```
Sub CreateCopies()
    Dim WBk             As Workbook  
    Set WBk = Workbooks("Gap Master")  

    '# Run the CopyForName for each of your manager names, e.g.:
    CopyForName WBk, "Snuth", "John"
    CopyForName WBk, "Zemens", "David"
    CopyForName WBk, "Bonaparte", "Napoleon"
    CopyForName WBk, "Mozart", "Wolfgang"

End Sub
```

Now, some revisions to your subroutine so that it is generic enough to perform the function for *all* managers:

```
Sub CopyForName(wkbkToCopy as Workbook, lastName as String, firstName As String)
    'This will prevent the alert from popping up when overwriting graphs, etc
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim strFileName     As String
    Dim WS              As Worksheet

    FPath = "C:\Users\mmarshall\Documents\GAP\GAP Development"
    FName = lastName & " GAP " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

    '## I consolidated your 3 loops in to 1 loop
    For Each WS In wkbkToCopy.Worksheets
        WS.Visible = (WS.Range("C4") = lastName & ", " & firstname)
    Next

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    'Copies sheets from your Gap Master file:
    wkbkToCopy.Sheets.Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)  

    '## I think you're trying to delete the default sheets in the NewBook:
    NewBook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete

    If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
    Else
        NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        NewBook.Close
    End If

      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: David, yes I have several other macros taht do the same for other managers.  I had to modify the "Gap master" to "Gap mastr.xlsm" but and then it worked flawlessly!  THANK YOU.

Comment: One last question: How I can turn the file path into a variable? Right now it can only be run on my machine, but I need to set it up so it will run on any PC, and still create the directory.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Use `FPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\GAP\GAP Development"`  This uses what is known as an [environment variable](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html)  and should be reliable for use on other computers.

Comment: This is runing well with one exception:  Instead of only copying the sheets that are assigined to a particular Manager, it is copying everything and hiding the sheets that do not belong to that manager.  I'd like to get this to only copy sheets for a particular manager to keep the file size down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After your line:

```
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
```

insert:

```
NewBook.Close
```

This should cause you to "fall back" to the original workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Step1:**
Change

```
Set WBk = ("Gap Master")
```

To

```
Set WBk = ActiveWorkbook
```

**Step 2:**
Also add another line:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
WBk.Activate '''''add this line''''''
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, cobbling together several different pieces of code:

```
Sub VPFiles()
Dim WBk             As Workbook
Set WBk = ThisWorkbook

'# Run the CopyForName for each of your manager names, e.g.:
CopyForName WBk, "Doe", "Christopher"
CopyForName WBk, "Smith", "Mark"
CopyForName WBk, "Randall", "Tony"
CopyForName WBk, "Jordan", "Steve"
CopyForName WBk, "Marshall", "Ron"



End Sub
```

Followed By This:

```
Sub CopyForName(wkbkToCopy As Workbook, lastName As String, firstName As String)
'This will prevent the alert from popping up when overwriting graphs, etc
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim NewBook         As Workbook
Dim strFileName     As String
Dim WS              As Worksheet


FPath = "\\filesrv1\department shares\Sales"
FName = lastName & " GAP " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

'## I consolidated your 3 loops in to 1 loop
For Each WS In wkbkToCopy.Worksheets
    WS.Visible = (WS.Range("K4") = lastName & ", " & firstName)

Next

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add


'Copies sheets from your Gap Master file:
wkbkToCopy.Sheets.Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

'This delets all unnecessary sheets in the NewBook:
NewBook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete
For Each WS In Worksheets
If WS.Visible <> True Then WS.Delete
Next

    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    NewBook.Close


  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```